# .net youtube library integration

Tags: .net, api, youtube

I have some problem for integrate youtube api on my webapp, I alredy use Analytics spi and this work, but when I try to add youtube service I get this error:

```
Il tipo 'Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService' è definito in un assembly di cui manca il riferimento. Aggiungere un riferimento all'assembly 'Google.Apis, Version=1.10.0.25332, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab'.
```

here the code

```
    using Google.Apis;
using Google.Apis.Auth;


using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Analytics.v3;
using Google.Apis.Analytics.v3.Data;

using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;

public class DashBoard 
    {


    protected ServiceAccountCredential credential = null;
    protected AnalyticsService analytics_service = null;
    protected YouTubeService youTube_service = null; 

.....
```

the line that create the error is this: protected YouTubeService.... removing this all work, adding this I get the error

what can I check for find the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Three points you need to check,

1. referenced version of Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService it might be possible that your trying to use different version of the reference than what is required by the youtube data api
2. In Google developer console, enable status of youtube data api
3. Update Google Api Client library through nuget package manager